# Able to access adapter procedure even after application authenticity is failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

Methods login() is defined in adapter.xml file. Even if Authentication failure occured, The method in my adapter is getting called. Below is the log.

```
[INFO    ] FWLSE0127E: Authenticity check failed for application 'myApp'. sharedData = com.company , challengeData = 675031C602476C671502N230615X5612F7F9S438718C069969N733313C511262X1A3E6788S640430N605556N379100C826824X8D3B856DS763514N594083C711666X22D23A91S077718N233880XEB3A98EAS571876X11FF1405S . [project MyProject]
[WARNING ] FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'wl_authenticityRealm': login fail [project MyProject]
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [MyProject] [/MyProject] [InvokeProcServlet]: Initialization successful.
[INFO    ] Inside login() method. [project MyProject]
```

I am using Worklight 6.2. Any reason why this is happening? Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: You should check your adapter xml file and make sure that login method is protected by a security test declared inside your server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml file.

ie: <procedure name="login" securityTest="YourSecurityTest"/>

Comment: @YoelNunez App authenticity protects both protected and unprotected resources. Also, If I protect login method with the secusity-test then how can I call it, since I am opening the login page as a result of failed security test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have app authenticity testing set as **Enable,servicing** instead of **Enabled blocking**.

Description:

**Enabled, servicing** – the Worklight Server tests the authenticity of the app. If the app fails the test, the Worklight Server outputs an information message to the log but services the app.

**Enabled, blocking** – the Worklight Server tests the authenticity of the app. If the app fails the test, the Worklight Server outputs an information message to the log and blocks the app.

You can change it in Worklight Console as documented here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/c_controlling_authenticity_testing.html?lang=en